# Is there a shorter/cleaner/better way to use this PHP file function?

Tags: php, file, function

I'm setting up a sports league website and I am using this code below to pull the names of all the teams from a single file, but I have to pull the team names in multiple places, on multiple pages, so have come to this solution. There will be 10-20 teams, but here's an example of what I'm doing, with just 5:

```
<?php echo ($team = file('teams.php', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES))? $team[1] : 'Unable to read file'; ?>
<?php echo ($team = file('teams.php', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES))? $team[2] : 'Unable to read file'; ?>
<?php echo ($team = file('teams.php', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES))? $team[3] : 'Unable to read file'; ?>
<?php echo ($team = file('teams.php', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES))? $team[4] : 'Unable to read file'; ?>
<?php echo ($team = file('teams.php', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES))? $team[5] : 'Unable to read file'; ?>
```

The teams.php file is just a simple list of team names, with line 1 blank or "---" so that the numbering can start at 1 instead of 0:

```
---
Team Name 1
Team Name 2
Team Name 3
Team Name 4
Team Name 5
```

I'm wondering if I can just set the `$team` variable once (at the top of each page, in a header.php file that is included in all the pages) and then just do a simpler call/include for each team name, something like this?:

header.php:

```
<?php $team = file('teams.php');?>
```

standings.php:

```
<?php $team[1];?>
<?php $team[2];?>
<?php $team[3];?>
<?php $team[4];?>
<?php $team[5];?>
```

Or maybe there's a completely different/better/simpler way of doing this.

Comment: I suggest you start using a simple database instead of such a file. Saves you all the hassle with parsing. If you insist on a file as a storage place then take a look at phps csv handling functions. They more or less offer what you are looking for: http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: @arkascha - Totally agree. Database management is the way to go. It also offers way more flexibiliy and scalability. There are no disdavantages using databases (besides maybe that you have to learn how to do it ;-))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with a simple array:

```
<?php
    $team = array(
    '01' => 'Team 01 Name',
    '02' => 'Team 02 Name',
    '03' => 'Team 03 Name',
    '04' => 'Team 04 Name',
    '05' => 'Team 05 Name'
);
?>
```

So I can then call the teams where needed on multiple pages, ie:

```
<?php echo $team['01']?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard PHP has loops - see http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if (false!==$file=file('./teams.php', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES))
   for ($x=0;5<$x;++$x)
     echo $file[$x];
else
  echo 'Unable to read file';
```